# Stuck on condition number derivation of the perturbed equation $(A + \Delta)\tilde{x} = b + \delta_b$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I've almost got what I want. We start with $Ax = b $ and $(A + \Delta)\tilde{x} = b + \delta_b$. What I have then is

\begin{align*}
\tilde{x} - x &= -A^{-1}\Delta\tilde{x} + A^{-1}\delta_b \\
\|\tilde{x} - x\| &\leq \|A^{-1}\|\left(\|\Delta\|\|\tilde{x}\| + \|\delta_b\|\right) \\
\frac{\|\tilde{x} - x\|}{\|x\|} &\leq \|A^{-1}\|\left(\|\Delta\|\frac{\|\tilde{x}\|}{\|x\|} + \frac{\|\delta_b\|}{\|x\|}\right)
\end{align*}
Now by $\|b\|\leq\|A\|\|x\|$ and $\frac{\|\tilde{x}\|}{\|x\|} \leq 1 + \frac{\|\tilde{x} - x\|}{\|x\|}$, we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{\|\tilde{x} - x\|}{\|x\|} &\leq \|A^{-1}\|\left(\|\Delta\|\left(1 + \frac{\|\tilde{x} - x\|}{\|x\|}\right) + \frac{\|\delta_b\|}{\|b\|}\|A\|\right)\\
&\leq \frac{\|\tilde{x} - x\|}{\|x\|}\|\Delta\|\|A^{-1}\| + \|A\|\|A^{-1}\|\left(\frac{\|\Delta\|}{\|A\|} + \frac{\|\delta_b\|}{\|b\|}\right)
\end{align*}
Taking the term on the rhs to the left and dividing gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{\|\tilde{x} - x\|}{\|x\|}&\leq \frac{\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|}{1 - \|\Delta\|\|A^{-1}\| }\left(\frac{\|\Delta\|}{\|A\|} + \frac{\|\delta_b\|}{\|b\|}\right).
\end{align*}

The problem is, I want to show that 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\|\tilde{x} - x\|}{\|x\|}&\leq \|A\|\|A^{-1}\|\left(\frac{\|\Delta\|}{\|A\|} + \frac{\|\delta_b\|}{\|b\|}\right),
\end{align*}
or in other words that $\|\Delta\|\|A^{-1}\| \leq 1$. The only bound I could find on the inverse is $1/\|A\| \leq \|A^{-1}\|$, which seems quite useless here. I'm not even sure if this is true, or if it is how do I show it. If not, where did I go wrong with my bounds? I'm really lost.

Comment: The last inequality  does not seem right for me in general case without restriction on $\Delta$.  Assume $\Delta$ is around $-A$. Then $\tilde x$ tends to infinity even if $A+\Delta$ is not singular. So the last inequality cannot be true.

Comment: After diving deep into google search results, I've found that to be the case. It seems the theorem we were supposed to prove somehow left out that detail. But thank you for taking the time to look at it anyways!